# Possible cases for Voice Translator

Tags: manual-testing

Can anyone share their experience testing this product? Or can advise best practice.
What can be tested in addition to the more or less logical translation, the number of supported languages, the correct recognition of the language in which people will speak? And what else?

Answer (score 1):

A possible set of test cases maybe:

- What happens when you start translation mode on but there's no sound
  input?
- What happens when you're translating from and to the same language?
- What happens when you translate at a volume above a certain
  threshold, above 100 decibels for example?
- What happens when the input voice (sound) pitch is altered?
- What happens when you translate at a really low threshold, around 20
  decibels?
- Also, as an exploratory step test by playing a song. In essence
  trying to translate a recorded song from one language to another.
- What happens with noise in ambience while the translation is in process?

Thanks!